# Matlab script not displaying images (imshow)

Tags: image, matlab, tiff

As the title says, I have looked over my code and I don't see a reason that my script is not printing out the images. In particular, I have solution code that **does** print out the images and I don't see any differences in the code so I'm at a bit of a loss. The code does throw errors at unfinished lines, however there should still be printed images in the first few sections, the errors shouldn't interfere with that so I still don't know why they don't print out. My code is as follows:

EDIT: Some of my classmates have the same error, I suspect it might be a path issue but I'm not sure how to address that.
EDIT2: I've reformatted the post to be clearer, sorry for including extraneous parts of this code. The document is a .mlx file, hence where there is code and text interspersed. The code did not run when I used the "Run section" button, however if I copied and pasted the coded into the Command Window it would run without issue.

```
P = phantom('Modified Shepp-Logan',300);
figure
imshow(P);
imwrite(P, 'raw1.tif');
```

Comment: How do points a to g relate to the image not being displayed? There is too many questions/conflicting questions here. Did you just copy pasted the entire homework without filter?

Comment: I can't tell if the points relate or if they're relevant, that's why I'm posting here, I wanted to provide all the code. This isn't homework, this is ungraded classwork which is why I felt vaguely comfortable posting it here. I can't imagine anything further on in my code causing the error, but I'm not familiar enough with Matlab to say that with confidence.

Comment: You need to post a clear question. g) is not even code that works, and its completely unrelated to displaying anything. We are working for free here to help you, but if you don't make it easy for us to help you then people simply won't. read [ask] and [mcve]. Also, "ungraded classwork" is just homework with a fancier name.

Comment: You need to shorten all this and only add the relevant information and code to the question you want to ask

Answer (score 0):

This section of the code seems to be working as expected when I tested it on MATLAB R2019b.

```
P = phantom('Modified Shepp-Logan',300);
figure
imshow(P);
imwrite(P, 'raw1.tif');
```

As an aside, all files will be saved to the current working directory unless otherwise specified.

### Steps Taken:

**To Run Script**

<kbd>Home Tab</kbd> → <kbd>New Script</kbd> → <kbd>Paste Script</kbd> → <kbd>Editor Tab</kbd> → <kbd>Run</kbd> 
and Give Script Save Name

**To Easily Open Exported/Saved File:**

Current Folder Side Panel → Right Click On File → <kbd>Open Outside MATLAB</kbd>

### Results

[image: Results]

### Extension: Other Cool Tricks (to avoid running unfinished lines)

Using `%%` can be used to separate the script into sections. Each section can be run using the <kbd>Run Section</kbd> Button in the EDITOR tab or can be run using the command:

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

MacOS: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

```
Section 1 Code

%%

Section 2 Code

%%

Section 3 Code
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**

Comment: I am using version R2020b, I'm not sure if that would be a significant difference? 
It seems like the "Run section" button doesn't actually run the code if there are errors anywhere in the .mlx file. Is there any documentation on bugs or weird behaviors like this recorded about Matlab R2020b?

Comment: Hmm, never heard of any bugs myself. Have you tried a .m file instead of live script .mlx file? Also it's surprising if they're no error messages that follow up.

Comment: I haven't tried a .m file, I'll try it out and see if it works better. Thanks!